# Removing lines with a single common field

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sort, uniq, join

I have a tab separated file that looks like this:

```
123   some text
123   some different text
334   some other text
341   more text
```

and I want to do two things. One is to order everything numerically (this is easy to do) and the other is to remove a line if it's number is already present. I.e. the output would look like this:

```
123   some text
334   some other text
341   more text
```

I tried getting a file of just the unique numbers, i.e.

```
123
334
341
```

and joining it with the original file with:

```
join -j 1 justNumbers.txt original.txt
```

but this gave me the original file back. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to sort/test for uniqueness the *first* field specifically, and your system has the GNU `coreutils` version of `sort`, then I think you could just use

```
sort -nu file
```

viz.

```
$ sort -nu file
123   some text
334   some other text
341   more text
```

From `info coreutils 'sort invocation'`

> The commands `sort -u` and `sort | uniq` are equivalent, but this
>   equivalence does not extend to arbitrary `sort` options.  **For
>   example, `sort -n -u` inspects only the value of the initial numeric
>   string when checking for uniqueness**, whereas `sort -n | uniq`
>   inspects the entire line.

Comment: That should work with any POSIX `sort`, not only the GNU one.

Comment: Note however that it you have one line starting with `0123` and another one starting with `123`, it will keep only one of them (which may be what you want). Use `sort -ubk1,1 | sort -n` if it's not what you want.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks (as usual) for your most knowledgeable input.

Answer (score 3):

Try this `awk`:

```
awk '!($1 in a){a[$1];print}' file
123   some text
334   some other text
341   more text
```

This assumes that file was sorted.